# SMSL M2 DAC Not found on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.10, soundcard

I have SMSL M2 DAC connected to PC by usb, and new fresh installed ubuntu 20.10. And my sound not working.
`alsamixer` on f6 shows my smsl card but can't find any mixers there.

```
pacmd list-cards | grep smsl
```

shows nothing.

```
aplay -l
```

shows my card.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 09da:769d A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:1024 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c76:161e JMTek, LLC. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It not writing anything about smsl m2

And if i enter ubuntu sound setting, i can't see this smsl.
What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Changed usb ports on my PC that was connected to SMSL M2 and after reboot ubuntu could see my card.